# Sailsjs with Sails-SqlServer and Waterline ORM

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sails.js, waterline

Having some trouble understanding the Waterline ORM documentation correctly. I am seeking advice on correct methodology in regards to querying a MSSQL database without having defined Models within my Sails API.

Thus far I have successfully created the necessary connections and downloaded the sails-sqlserver npm package.

I have a controller with the following code:

```
    module.exports = {

       /**
       * @name: all
       * @description: return a list of items
       **/

        all: function(req, res){

           /** as per Waterline documentation, use a use an arbitary model to create a raw SQL query **/

           Items.query("select * from table", function(err, resultSet){

              if(err) return res.send(err);

              return res.ok(resultSet);

           });          


        }
    }
```

Items.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

  }
};
```

Upon calling the route for the controller `GET /api/items` using Postman

The API does not return a response, it merely hangs, eventually timing out.

I have console.log() above the Items.query to ensure that the controller is being executed.

I have found that SQL Server is denying access to the server.

> The prelogin packet used to open the connection is structurally
>   invalid; the connection has been closed. Please contact the vendor of
>   the client library.

Comment: Seems to be a network configuration issue. I was able to sucesfully connect to a local network server without any issues.

The database i was trying to connect on is via VPN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am the maintainer of the [sails-sqlserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-sqlserver) Adapter.

Ensure that:

1. You can connect to the database using the same credentials through the SQL Server Workbench.
2. You're not behind any restrictive firewall or proxy that might be messing with your requests
3. You're using a supported version of SQL Server (2008 and above)

Comment: Hi Travis. Thank you for your comment. Turns out that I needed to use the encrypt: true option within my connections.js. Our vpn/firewall may have been the issue.

Comment: @goingsideways - be good to mark this answer as correct. Thanks for posting your question, as this answer assisted me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are upside down, you have to define your model with the attributes of your DB, for example:

**items.js**

```
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  connection: 'yourConnection',
  tableName: 'yourTableName',
  attributes: {
      id:{
        type:"number",
        primaryKey: true
      },
      name:{
        type:"string"
      },
      address:{
        type:"string"
      }
  }
};
```

Now when you call the route `GET localhost:1337/items` it will return all your items without having a function in your controller.

Note: assuming you are using localhost.